# Using awk to store a binary number in text file as string and then convert to hexadecimal

Tags: awk

I'm using `awk` to parse a text file.  The text file has four fields of byte data and appears as such:

```
11110000  10100000  10110000  10010000
```

I want to read the fields and convert them from binary to a hexadecimal.  Currently I'm using `printf %x`.  This way changes `11110000` into a decimal and then into a hex number.  This says the value of `1111000` is `0xA98760` instead of `0xF0`.

My code is simple and I'm new to BASH and Linux.

```
awk'{printf(%x %x %x %x, $1, $2, $3, $4)};
```

How can I store the string fields as the binary that it is and then convert to Hex?  I can get the hex number from the terminal using " bc <<< "obase=16;ibase=2; $variable"". When I try to script this I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an inelegant hack, but it works.  Declares a function b which takes a binary representation of a number and returns the decimal value.  Then relies on `printf` and its %x to show in hex.

```
$ awk 'func b(i, t,a,c){a=1;for(c=length(i);c>0;c--){t+=substr(i,c,1)=="1"?a:0;a*=2}return t}{printf "0x%x 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x\n",b($1),b($2),b($3),b($4)}' bin.txt
0xf0 0xa0 0xb0 0x90
```

Comment: This inelegant hack works!  Much appreciated!

Comment: @Jcwilli585 If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` only does decimal, octal and hexadecimal, not binary. You could use `perl` instead:

```
perl -lane 'BEGIN{$, = " "} print unpack "(H2)*", pack("(B8)4", @F)'
```

With `dc` and GNU `tac` (see also `tail -r` on some systems):

```
{ echo 16o2i; cat; echo f; } < file.txt | dc | tac
```

With `bc` (assuming your syntax error was about the `<<<` `zsh` operator used in a shell other than `zsh` or recent versions of `bash`/`ksh93`/`mksh`/`yash`)

```
{ echo 'obase=16; ibase=2'; tr -cs 01 '[\n*]'; } < file.txt | bc
```

Comment: I don't have Perl and there's no way to add it to the system I'm using.  I can get the hex number from the terminal using " bc <<< "obase=16;ibase=2; $variable"".  When I try to script this I get a syntax error.

Comment: @Jcwilli585 add that update to your question and you might get an answer for that part too

Comment: @Jcwilli585 you don't have Perl? I have my doubts

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pale '$_ = join $", map { sprintf "%X", oct "0b$_" } @F'
```

## Brief:

> ```
> Perl options:
>      -p => autoprint + implcit file read in/line, a.la., awk
>      -a => autosplit line into fields using default delimiter ' '
>      -l => ORS=IRS="\n"
>
> Perl standard variables:
>       $" => list separator, by default it is a single space " "
>       $_ => refers to the whole line, equivalent to $0 in awk
>       @F => fields got by splitting the current line, $1, $2,$3, ... $NF in awk
>
> Perl code:
>       map { body } list_of_items
>            Map takes in an input list and applies the code present in 
>            it's body on each element of this list to generate an output list.
> ```

```
      join <separator>, <list>
           Join takes in an input list and joins their elements by the 
           separator provided in the first argument.

       oct <number>
            When the input to this function is prefixed by a "0b", then
            it is treated to be a binary number and outputs the decimal
            equivalent.

       sprintf "%x" <decimal>
             This function whose format is "%x" treats the input as
             decimal and returns the equivalent number in hex.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to add a few words of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If the system you're targetting has GNU Bash, you can take advantage of its support, in it arithmetic expressions, for bases other than just octal and hex. For instance:

```
bash$ echo $(( 2#1011 | 2#1100 ))   # bitwise OR of 11 and 12
15
```

Okay, so if we take this data:

```
11110000  10100000  10110000  10010000
```

and somehow massage it into this syntax and evaluate it:

```
$(( 2#11110000101000001011000010010000 ))
```

we get the value

```
4037062800
```

(Yes, this works on 32 bit builds of bash; we don't get a negative.)

We can do this very simply:

```
echo $(( 2#$(tr -d ' ' < file) ))
4037062800
```

The only problem is that this is, to an extent, `eval` in disguise. We are interpolating the output of some command, based on the contents of a file, into an expression which then gets evaluated. If `file` is obtained from an untrusted source, there could be security implications. For instance, I wouldn't put this into a CGI script under Apache, where `file` comes the POST data of a form submitted by arbitrary Internet users.